# How to link HTML file to CSS in Windows Notepad (NOT NOTEPAD++)

Tags: html, css

I've been looking all over the internet for a way to link HTML to CSS in the preinstalled Notepad program on Windows. I have tried using the system path, but that didn't work. Is there any way I could do this without having to use Notepad++? I'd rather not download it. Summed up, how do I link an HTML file to a CSS file using Window's Notepad?

Comment: What do you mean with link HTML to CSS in an editor?

Comment: Yes, what do you mean by link? also, I use Notepad++ all the time, it's a relatively light program that just changes font colors to make it a little more readable.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think what you're looking for is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">` (assuming you are editing your HTML file in Notepad.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just look at where your Notepad file is saved.  If your CSS file is in the same directory, you can add this href attribute to your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_styles.css">
```